# The suggestion to create a Tag wiki should be only there if the user can actually create one

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

Clicking on a tag that has no tag wiki shows the following message atop all questions (except the tag name might differ, obviously):

[image]

However, clicking on it greets one with

> Tag wikis can be edited by users with more than 2000 reputation, provided:
>
> - They are in the top 20 answerers for this tag or
> - They have a total score of 100 or more for this tag

I'm quite obviously not in that category for a tag that has a mere three questions, but anyway: Providing the link to create the tag wiki is only helpful in the first place if the user *is actually allowed to create anything*.

Comment: I've a feeling that I'd seen this requested on MetaSO already, but can't find it right now to see what the result was... :/

Comment: Ah, the joys of having separate metas per site – that leaves the question where general engine-related bugs should go. I'm assuming though, that questions can be moved.

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion for a tag wiki, feel free to start a CW question where people can pitch in trying to fill it up. No need to start multiple answers, we need **one** wiki in the end!

Comment: @IvoFlipse Seems to be fixed (see answer). If so, how about closing?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality seems to have changed since original situation. I see only `"help us edit this wiki"` link when no tag wiki page exists and on that page I'm being informed that

> "You do not yet have tag wiki edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed."

So, anybody should be able to suggest edits to tag wikis but they become publicly available only at some later point.

However, when asking a new question and creating a tag that doesn't exist I get just an empty hover-up box what [seems as a bug to me](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2205/empty-tooltip-for-non-existing-tag).