# Empty tooltip for non-existing tag

Tags: support, tags, user-interface

When asking a new question and creating a tag that doesn't exist I get just an empty hover-up box.

I haven't tried to actually post a question with a bogus tag, so I'm not sure if this behaviour occurs only on the "Ask Question" page.

Comment: FYI: Posting a question with a non-existing "bogus" tag will [create that tag](http://superuser.com/privileges/create-tags) - that's where almost every tag on the site has originally come from.

Comment: if you have enough rep to create a new tag, that is...

Comment: Can you still reproduce this?

Answer (score 3):

What else would you expect to happen for tags that do not yet exist?

Comment: Maybe no empty popup... (I.e. if there's no relevant content, don't show it.)